# Upgrading Drush from 4.4 to 7.1

Tags: drush, theming

Following instructions [here](https://drupal.org/node/901828), I used the command `drush dl drush` to install the newer version of Drush. Then, when I attempted `drush omega-export` (the reason I was upgrading was to have access to these newer omega commands) I received a message indicating that drush was still pointing to the older version of drush.

If the server was based in my home computer environment (win7) I would change the PATH variable to point to the newer version. However, since the server I am working on is remote (onyxServers, typical LAMP stack) I am unsure how to make the `drush CLI` point to the new version.

Can anyone point me to  a resource? If it was my own linux machine I would be able to figure it out but being hosted confuses things a bit.

UPDATE: I have examined the output of the 'env' command, and noticed that the location of drush, new or old version, is not listed in the PATH variable:

> PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/dukkha/perl5/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/lib/courier-imap/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/dukkha/bin

Is it possible that the path to drush is stored within the drush shell or something?

Comment: See [How do I upgrade drush from 3 to the latest release?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36810/how-do-i-upgrade-drush-from-3-to-the-latest-release).

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I guess I posted this question a little too quickly! The path to the drush command can be altered through editing the .bash_profile file.